# Get signed SOAP Message in client using WCF

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, ws-security

I'm consuming a web service (Java) from my own web service (WCF). I need to get the signed SOAP Message request (with security header signed) that i'm sending to Java web service and save it (file, database,...).

I've tried using a IClientMessageInspector using BeforeSendRequest method, but the request is not signed yet. Is there any way to get signed request before send it?

```
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {

       var content = request.ToString();
       // request is not signed yet

       return null;
    }
```

Another option could be to sign the request 'manually'... I did it using SoapEnvelope class (Microsoft.Web.Services3) with .asmx web services in the past. 
I've tried using a CustomMessageHeader but it was impossible (for me).

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: I finally found a **solution** that works for me. I used WCF tracing.
In one of the steps you must edit the machine.config file on the client. It may not work for everyone

How To:
1. Modify config file for tracing. You need to add *diagnostics* and *system.diagnostics* info.

```
    <configuration>  
     <system.serviceModel>      
      <diagnostics>
       <!-- I need logMessagesAtTransportLevel only -->
       <messageLogging
          logEntireMessage="false"
          logMalformedMessages="false"
          logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
          logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" 
          logKnownPii="true"
          maxMessagesToLog="1000"
          maxSizeOfMessageToLog="200000"/>
       </diagnostics>   
      <binding>...</binding>
      <client>...</client>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.diagnostics>
     <sources>     
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"
              logKnownPii="true"
              switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing">
      <listeners>         
        <add name="xmlTracer" />
      </listeners>
     </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>     
     <add name="xmlTracer" type="MyNamespace.MyTraceListender, MyNamespace" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
   </system.diagnostics>
 </configuration>
```

2. Create the class MyTreceListener that inherits from TraceListener

   ```
   namespace MyNamespace
   {
       public class MyTraceListender : System.Diagnostics.TraceListener
       {
           public override void Write(string message)
           {             
               Debug.WriteLine(message);
           }

           public override void WriteLine(string message)
           {
               Debug.WriteLine(message); 
               // Here we have the signed SOAP !!
               // Make sure it's the request, this method is invoked many      times  
           }       
        }
   }
   ```

You can get the signed SOAP message but the *BinarySecurityToken* is removed.

```
   ...<o:BinarySecurityToken><!--Removed--></o:BinarySecurityToken>...
```

3. If you need the PII information in the message, you must edit de machine.config in the client.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework{version}\Config\machine.config
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64{version}\Config\machine.config

Add *enableLoggingKnownPii* parameter

```
    <system.serviceModel>
      <machineSettings enableLoggingKnownPii="true"/>
      ...
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Now, you can get the complete signed SOAP message when you call the service.

I hope it helps someone. :)

Comment: What kind of signing do you want to use ? If the signature is WS-*, WCF probably have a binding to do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To get the message with the elements signed, you have to create a custom

channel, in which you will be able to act on the message.

You can follow the two following links for creating a channel :

- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/BizTalk-Server-REST-Error-52fa4ff0
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16625.biztalk-server-rest-services-error-handling.aspx (For the explanations, directly go to *Implementing the solution* paragraph)

The custom channel should then included in a customBinding. It must be the last element :

```
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="myBinding">
            <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10" />
            <security messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncryptAndEncryptSignature" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11" />
            <httpsTransport />
            <myBindingChannel />
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

The new channel must be the last in order to have the most processed message.

If you need to convert your binding, take a look at You can use this tool to make it : http://webservices20.cloudapp.net/.

Comment: The problem is not how to sign the request correctly, the problem is how to get the request signed (like you can see in fiddler, for example) and save it. I can use a binding for create the correct request, but i can't access to the signed request.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I think you have to create a custom channel. You have a sample here : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/BizTalk-Server-REST-Error-52fa4ff0 (and the explanations http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16625.biztalk-server-rest-services-error-handling.aspx, start at Implementing the solution)

Comment: The custom channel should then included in a customBinding.

Comment: Thanks, I take a look !!

Comment: Hi, Rom Eh. Finally, I tried using this example (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751495(v=vs.100).aspx) but the result is the same: the message is not signed yet.

Comment: Hello. You have built a custom binding, and put your component at last ?